# iOS custom error popup

Tags: ios, error-handling, uialertcontroller

I would like to add "more info" collapsible accordion into my error alert view. So it will expand with additional information about the err after user presses it. And of course it will animate the size of error alert too. How it can be done? Maybe there is already existing solution for what I need?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The standard UIAlertView does not allow this. You'll have to make your own view that mimicks the appearance of an alert view (using a UIVisualEffectView and possibly even a UIInterpolatingMotionEffect if you really want it to look like the real thing). Takes a fair but of work, especially if you want to support older iOS versions. And of course with every new iOS version that changes the appearance of alerts, you'll have to update the code. You might be better off just going with a completely different appearance unique to your app.

Once you have made that custom view, you can add the extra field as a hidden text field. When the triangle button is pressed, you set the height of that hidden field to 0, unhide it, then animate the height of the text field and the height of the containing view to their new values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom alert view
https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

You can add whatever animation you want.